# Encrypting URLs in PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I have uploaded some files on server. The link provided to me is pretty simple i-e; no signs/ symbols etc. If I provide the same link to the user for downloading the data, it might result in hacking of my server or loss of data. Now my question is how to encrypt this kind

```
  www.hello.com/myApp/myFile.mp3
```

of url and provide the encrypted url to the user which the browser can understand.

Regards

Comment: why should this result in hacking your server?

Comment: You can use urlEncode/rawURLEncode (any kind of transformation can be used as an encryption as well), but that won't fix your problem, if you say that you have a security problem as it is. You should probably explain what you worry about in terms of security, as your problem might be more basic.

Comment: @griffin just consider this one possibility. If the user sets the url like: www.hello.com/myApp , he will see the whole list of files uploaded and will be able to download it. I want to hide this part /myApp/file.txt with encrypted text.

Comment: I take it you use apache and have +Index option set - just disable it. Also, you're talking about what is called "security by obscurity" - dont't do it, because it's no real security. Better: Require a password for the files you don't want to be accessed by anyone. Easy to do (if you have apache, you can use htpasswd for example with basic auth module) and gives way more security already than just "hiding" something.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I misunderstand, but are you trying to prevent someone from downloading the file unless you tell them it's ok to download it?

Then the threat is that someone may find the file linked on a search engine or be able to guess it.

There are a few ways to make that threat less likely.

1. Make the url very long and unguessable. Simply rename the file to some random value could work. From the command line (linux)

   `echo http://example.com/file.mpe $(date) | md5sum
   d8a5e8d341135379b8ad38f1d06970be`

   Or even easier, choose a random password from http://tooln.net/pw/ and rename the file to one of the passwords without symbols. Either is difficult to guess.
2. If you know the person, you could easily share a password and set a password on the directory. You can turn on [passwords per directory](http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/password-protect-directory.shtml) through apache.
3. Turn off indexing of the site through [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/).

Answer (score 0):

A URL can be encrypted, but if a browser can understand it, decrypting it would be a trivial process for a hacker. I'm assuming what you want to do is to prevent too many people from accessing your URL. To do this, you will have to have either some sort of user login system or an IP based limitation. Both of these would have to be backed by a database.

Instead of linking directly to the file, you would link to something like `download.php?fileid=$some_file_id` and in your database, you just insert the user ID (or IP address) and file ID every time the file is download. Then to display the file back to the user, you would check how many downloads of that file have been made by the user and if it is less than your threshold, e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downloads WHERE user = :user AND file_id = :id
```

Then get PHP to echo the contents of the file to the browser.

Add other clauses such as limiting it to `X` downloads in the past 24 hours, etc. or however you would like to work it.

Other things you could do would be storing the files outside the document root (or protecting direct access with `.htaccess` or similar), and including a hash of the file name in the link, so someone couldn't just do `download.php?fileid=1` and guess the next one is `download.php?fileid=2`.

Comment: Nitpicking, but: Of course you can encrypt an url - it's just a string. Plus: You don't need a database (and you're already talking about an sql based here, there are others as well) to implement some access system. As he probably runs apache by what he is saying, htpasswd basic auth can do the same including user groups, without any database or code besides one time apache config/htaccess file, which you can even generate online.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the actual purpose of doing this. I didn't see your comments below the question.

Comment: I think you actually understand it better than the OP. After your edit I just upvoted it, as I think it perfectly fits what he is trying to achieve (thought doesn't really ask for ...)